# Can I use this circuit to control model trains with?

Tags: transistors, current-measurement, attiny

I am currently researching and developing several arduino/attiny projects for model railway applications.

One of the projects is a method to 'catch' an analog train and gently slow it down using a single transistor in combination with a low Frequency PWM signal (20Hz - 100Hz).

Several of these modules together can realize a shuttle service

The following circuit can do precisely that.
[image]
(N.B. I forgot to draw a line from the upper power rail to the upper brake section's rail)

How it is supposed to work? A train running under 12VDC is moving from the main track to the braking section. The transistor Q5 is on 100% dutycycly at this point. As soon as the locomotive is fully on the the braking section, the train's current will flow through Rshunt, creating a small voltage. This voltage is measured by an attiny chip so the chip can know when there is a train arriving.

As soon as a train is detected, the dutycycle will slowly decrease to 0%. This will stop the train and render it powerless. If you than flip switch SW2, you revert the voltage and train will jump in the direction to where it came from. The attiny itself will become powerless.

This method with a single transistor is shortcircuit proof when the maintrack and brake section are electronically physically connected by a train. Using an H bridge on the braking section, would cause short circuit problems.

Theoretically I can duplicate and mirror this entire circuit with the intention of also gently accelerating the train. Though this is possible I would be using relative many components. I would be using 2 attiny chips for one section of tracks.

So preferably I want to use a similar circuit as below.

[image]
The circuit would do the same as the first circuit. It waits for a train until a voltage is detected on Rshunt3 than it turns down the dutcycle of Q4 untill the train stops.

Here comes the difference. When the voltage is flipped (and I make the attiny aware of this via an input which is not present on the schematic) than the attiny will increase the dutycycle of the other transistor (which probably can be on the same output) from 0% to 100%. This should gently accelerate the train to 100% before it reaches the main track again.

I am not sure if this circuit will actually work. And that is where this post is about.
In the second schematic, the attiny ground pin is not directly connected to the rails anymore. Instead the attiny ground is connected through one of the diodes of the bridge rectifier to the 0V rail.

So my questions:

1. Will the transistors (to be replaced by N channel MOSFETs) conduct and do what I described?
2. Will the current measurement still work? Answered in comments: **No, these lines will blow up the atting by putting 12V directly to the input pins**
3. Are the other problems I am not foreseeing? **point 2**
4. And depending on the answers to the above three questions. Can I make this work? And if so, how can I make it work?

EDIT:
Looking at answers I believe one thing is not entirely clear. The +/- lines (the top and the bottems lines) can only be toggled via SW2. So the voltage is either 12V <> 0V or 0V <> 12V. The bridge rectifier always makes this 12V-0V and the LM7805 will always supply 5V to the attiny even though it has no common ground with the 12V supply.

Comment: The 2nd circuit is not going to work and will **damage** the ATTiny uC! Also Q3 will **never switch off**. For Q3 to be off, the uC would have to output around 11 V. The uC has a supply of only 5V so it cannot output a higer voltage. A higher supply voltaeg will damage it. You need a **level shifter** circuit to control Q3. Also pin 2 of the uC will get close to 12 V which violates the maximum input voltage (close to Vcc so 5 V). I **strongly** suggest that you look on train-hobbyists forums what circuits they use and learn from that.

Comment: Also the fact that you "simply" disconnect the ground of the LM7805 from the 12 V supply rails (to which the current sense resistors are connected) is really a very big **NO**. I estimate that you have a 99.99% of destroying several components if you build the 2nd circuit.

Comment: What's wrong with using [DCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Command_Control). It's pretty much the right way to go.

Comment: I see the mistake with the voltage measurements, those will both blow up the attiny. I do not think however that Q3 will be on all the time. It is wired the exact same as the other transistor. The top and the bottem rail are either 12V-0V or 0V-12V depending on SW2. The problem of DCC is that you need to buy 25€ decoders per train. 
Bimpelrekkie, if the current measurement lines are gone, the lm7805 should still work despite it has no common ground with the 12v supply.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am one of those guys to whom people ask their electronic questions on the trainforum to. I built my own working DCC central with my own software. I believed this to be a valid question for here as it concerns a very specific electrical problem. I am currently thinking that I need atleast one optocoupler to detect current with. I am still not sure whether the transistors will work

Comment: *the lm7805 should still work despite it has no common ground with the 12v supply* The issue is not with the LM7805. The issue is elsewhere and related to the current measurement. The fact that you don't "see" that means you do not have enough circuit design experience yet to be able to pull this off. If there were a few small changes that could be done to make it work, I'd share them. But your 2nd circuit has quite fundamental issues. You cannot just take the 1st circuit and copy-paste/mirror parts of it and make that work.

Comment: Before you start insulting me can you read everything and not only just those parts so you can insult me. I have already said that I realized why the current sense lines would destroy the attiny. I have also updated the question with this information. I totally see that I hooked up 12v to the attiny input and I admit it was stupit. I am currently adding a 4 chn optocoupler to achieve a galvanic insulation for both transistors as well as for the current sensing